# Define a table of constants using arrays

Tags: java

In Java, I would like to create some kind of table of information, made of arrays of `final` `static` constants. I would like to initialize them at declaration time. I tried with array, `ArrayList`, `HashMap`, but I cannot find a syntax that allows me to write something similar to this.

```
public static final (something) names = {
        { "Albert Einstein", number_1, number_2 } ,
        { "Isaac Newton", number_3, number_4 } ,
        { "Pitagora", number_5, number_6 } ,
};
```

As you can see is an array of arrays, and creates an equivalent to a DB table. The columns of this sort of table are made of different types (although all data in the first place will always be strings, in second place integers, and so on)

What shall I put in place of (something)?

Comment: What are `number_1`, and others? And how do you want to access the information. This is an importance factor to decide what data structure you need.

Comment: They are just examples, in this case it would be an array of triplets, string, integer, integer. It's not really important how to access the information, rather how to initialize easily with static final data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a lack of strong typing, ie using `Object`, you can simply use an array of array of Object.

This compiles:

```
public static final Object [][] names = {
    { "Albert Einstein", number_1, number_2 } ,
    { "Isaac Newton", number_3, number_4 } ,
    { "Pitagora", number_5, number_6 } ,
};
```

Comment: Oh this is another solution, even more compact, although if I understood well, I could also add a completely different object, right? For example one could be { number_6, array, "Joe", number_7 }

Comment: Yes. Actually this exact datatyoe is used by Hibernate (a well respected persistence framework) to represent rows of data from an arbitrary database query - ie a table of data! Each rows is returned as an array of Object (since the framework doesn't know what types the columns will be) and there's an array of those to make a "table".

Comment: After all, these have to be constants, so I don't mind about double-checks on types and so on, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays represent a list of *the same* type of data. Therefore,

```
 { "Albert Einstein", number_1, number_2 }
```

should not be an array. In fact, it cannot be anything standard in Java, because this is something specific to your application.

Make some class like

```
public class MyData {
    public final String name;
    public final int number1;
    public final int number2;

    public MyData(String name, int number1, int number2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number1 = number1;
        this.number2 = number2;
    }
}
```

And declare

```
public static final MyData[] names = new MyData[] {
    new MyData("Albert Einstein", number_1, number_2) ,
    new MyData("Isaac Newton", number_3, number_4),
    new MyData("Pitagora", number_5, number_6)
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is compact and clear, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are looking for a custom class:

```
public class Scientist {
    private String name;
    private int numInventions;
    private int numStudents;
    public Scientist(String name, int numInventions, int numStudents) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numInventions = numInventions;
        this.numStudents = numStudents;
    }
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public int getNumInventions() {return numInventions;}
    public int getNumStudents() {return numStudents;}
}
```

Now you can initialize your array as follows:

```
Scientist[] scientists = new Scientist[] {
    new Scientist("Albert Einstein", number_1, number_2),
    new Scientist("Isaac Newton", number_3, number_4),
    new Scientist("Pitagora", number_5, number_6)
};
```

Comment: I always forget how Java is space-wasting :) Probably yes, this solution and another one almost identical are the correct choices, thanks.

Comment: @Beppi's I prefer the word "clarity" over "space-wasting", but yes, you've got the idea right :)

Comment: Yes, clarity is another face of the coin "space-wasting" indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 public static final String[][] names = { namesarray1, namesarray2 };
```

Comment: Unfortunately as you can see it is an array of arrays, and the internal array should contain different types of data.

Answer (score 0):

1) Encapsulate. Create a `Class` that gets together a set of attributes (the name and its related attributes)

2) Create an array `[]` or a `Collection` (use a subclass) to hold values (instances) of that class

Comment: Would you make me an example? Can I initialize it directly during the declaration?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to do it in the `static` initialiser e.g.

```
public static final List<Something> names;

static {
    names = new List<Something>();
    // init here below using .add()
    names.add(Something); // something would contain the 3 fields you're grouping together
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a solution but I was looking for something more compact and clear :)